# Change a content a maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, docker, nexus

I'm currently changing a docker image. The docker image creates a server that allows running some experiments. To adapt its functionality for my purpose, I have to change a class that is contained in a dependency jar file. In the pom.xml file, such jar dependency is downloaded with its dependencies from a nexus repository. I presume that a possible solution is to create a repository in the nexus repository (localhost) and then upload the jar file with its dependencies, right? Anyway, I would have no idea how I can do it. Below is the code concerning it.
Could someone help me up, please?

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liveontologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>pinpointing-experiments</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>       
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you're on the right track. What you're asking about is called a "deploy" in maven. So to deploy your jar generally you'll need to:

1. Create your nexus instance
2. Add your new repository to your pom file
3. Add the `maven-deploy-plugin` to your pom
4. Make your code changes
5. Deploy your jar with the `mvn deploy` command

Two good resources for lots of details on the steps and the exact content to add to your pom.

https://www.baeldung.com/maven-deploy-nexus

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html

Comment: Hey @marouanenadir hit the checkbox on the answer to let others know that this solution worked for you. Learn more https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers